# nytimes.com has big blank area when I view using Firefox. Looks ok with IE

Tags: firefox, website, flash

Anybody else with this problem?

It's the only website I have trouble with.   I've uninstalled, re-installed Adobe Flash, thinking that might the cause.   I've cleared the browser cache.    It's been happening for months.   I contacted nytimes support without any response.

Comment: Sounds like you have ad blocker turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View->Zoom->Reset fixed it, as documented here:

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/272443&s=os%20x